# CKD solenoid burns on first trigger

Tags: solenoid-valve

I am trying to use a solenoid valve in order to switch on tap water using a switch on the live supply to the solenoid, but every time I switch on the first time, the solenoid activates and burns immediately, leaving the valve in a normally open state.

I am using a solenoid valve from CKD corporation:
Serial: 4Z13
Model: AB41038.
Operating specifications:
-220 V
-50 Hz
I am supplying 199 V to it through the switch.

What could be cause of my problem?

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheet for the solenoid. Are you providing 199V **ac** at 50Hz?

Comment: Best to contact supplier since no datasheet avail.

Comment: How did you measure 199 V?

Comment: That does not look like a CKD part number. Either datasheet or photo of nameplate.

Answer (score 1):

If this solenoid is truly rated for 220 VAC 50 Hz, you are driving it with 199 VAC 50 Hz, and it "burns", then one or the other above is not true.

A solenoid rated for 220 VAC 50 Hz should be able to handle normal line voltage anywhere in the world without damage.  If this is happening, then you probably got a coil intended for a different voltage.  Check what it says right on the solenoid.  The voltage and frequency requirements are usually written there.

If you got the wrong solenoid, **contact the manufacturer**.  If one rated for 220 VAC 50 Hz "burns" when that or a lesser voltage is applied, **contact the manufacturer**.

I don't know what you expect us to say either way.  No, we can't hand out personal exemptions to the laws of physics here.